# how can I create executable file for the program written on Java?

Tags: java, executable

everyone, how can I create executable file for the program written on Java in Eclipse Helios? I mean to create small icon to be able start program only by double-clicking on its icon, thanks in advance
**edited**
I mean executable for Windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Export .jar in eclipse. [(how to)](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_export)
2. Use JSmooth [(info)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSmooth) to make an .exe file. [(how to)](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html)

Comment: Can you extract the jar from the exe, if you like to use it on a different OS?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that shows you how to make a jar file from eclipse.

If Java is installed on the computer, you can execute your application by doubleclicking the jar file:

http://ecs.victoria.ac.nz/Courses/COMP205_2009T1/TutorialEclipseExportToJar

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what platform you are using. There are 2 ways I can think of.

The easiest way is for you to create a *.bat file (in Windows) that contains the `java YourApp` command line.

If you want to create a more fancy installer and executable, you can use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) script to do so. Since you are using eclipse, consider trying [EclipseNSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EclipseNSIS_-_NSIS_plugin_for_Eclipse) to generate the NSIS script, which is much faster and easier than writing it yourself from ground up.

Comment: .bat on windows and  .sh on *nix

Comment: You can create a file in Windows, then rename the extension to ".bat". That's it. You will notice the icon automatically change. Double clicking it will execute it, so you want to right click on it, then "edit" that will open that bat file in a notepad. Then type it your java command and save it.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for this situation is to launch the app. using [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).  JWS can not only create desktop and start menu launch items, but provides automatic updates, cross-platform compatibility and much more.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a 1-line metafile to specify which class the JVM should look for to start with the main(String[]) method.
2. Run the command jar cmf [metafileName] [jarfileName] [classfiles] [img/txtDirectories]
3. You have an executable jar file - type in "java -jar jarfileName" or, directly "jarfileName" at your prompt. On windows, you can also double click on the jar file logo/name to get it started.

Good wishes, - M.S.

PS: Here is the link to a more detailed tutorial:
http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html