# how i can create executable file in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I create executable file for the program written on Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765371/how-can-i-create-executable-file-for-the-program-written-on-java)

hi, 
   how i can create executable file in java. i want to set java home by creating my executable file. so please give some example how i can set java home by executable file

Comment: before asking an SO question, you should always do a search to see if someone has asked it already.

Comment: The question is unclear. If you compile a class with a main mehtod, it is executable. If your system isn't configured the right way, you have to fix that. You're talking about JAVA_HOME? Be precise! You want to create a batch- or script-file to start your program with a specific JAVA_HOME? Well, first, choose an operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following options:

[JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/

Ans Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) thread for more options

Answer (score 0):

> hi, how i can create executable file in java.

This has been asked and answered many times before on SO;
e.g. [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file).

> i want to set java home by creating my executable file.

That simply makes no sense.  You cannot set an environment variable (e.g. $JAVA_HOME) or Java property (java.home) by creating an executable file.

> so please give some example how i can set java home by executable file

That makes slightly more sense, but the question is where do you want to set it.  If you want to set `$JAVA_HOME` / `%JAVA_HOME%` for a shell, you have to do this by executing a shell builtin-command, or by launching a new shell.  You could set the Java `java.home`property in a currently executing Java program, but there is no point ... it will most likely just break things.

---

Based on your past questions, I'm going to make a wild guess and that you are trying to set the `$JAVA_HOME` / `%JAVA_HOME%` for a Tomcat instance.  If that is the case, then:

- for UNIX you should set it in the wrapper script that launches Tomcat,
- for Windows you can set it as a command option in the Tomcat service launcher;
  see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html.