# How to create a .exe for my java program using Jsmooth?

Tags: java, jsmooth

Suppose I had a simple program called Main.class created from eclipse.

How would I create an .exe for that program? Does it have to be a .jar to work???

**This is what I get when compiling:**

---

Starting compilation

Scanning skeleton...

Loading Jar...

Adding Jar to Resources...

Adding Properties to Resources...

Loading icon...

Compilation failed!

- Error: null

---

(note I set the java version to 1.4)

The program itself is just a picture. There are no syntax errors at all. 
I had a little of bit of confusion in deciding what to put in the fields for every process in JSmooth. I only had one file to put anyway.

Comment: I don't know Jsmooth but I came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765371/how-can-i-create-executable-file-for-the-program-written-on-java]. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

After messing around with the parameters, I've fixed my case of "Error: null"

My solution : Replace the "not-working executable icon (.ico file)" in your JSmooth project by , for example, a very simple PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue users come across. JSmooth seems very limited in the size and bitdepth of icons it supports. I don't know why it doesn't just toss it on as a resource like WinRun4J and let Windows pick the icon to use instead of preferring 32x32.

Try reducing the bit-depth and removing your larger icons to be just 16x16, 32x32 and maybe 48x48 and or 64x64 with only 4 or 8 bits of depth. Those are the settings that work for many people. Some use 32 bit PNGs but the docs say they are sampled down to 256 colors anyway.

- http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html#N1011A
- http://sourceforge.net/p/jsmooth/bugs/84/
- http://sourceforge.net/p/jsmooth/discussion/297041/thread/294c7f61/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem and it was ultimately to do with my icon file.

No idea what was wrong with it but clearing the icon option fixed the problem.