# How to generate executable of java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable

I am trying to make an executable file of my Java Application but I don't know how to do that.

I know how to generate an executable jar file, but I want to make an executable application.

I'm using eclipse indigo to make the java application and to generate the jar file.

How to make the executable?

Comment: What do you mean by Executable Application? An exe?

Comment: @NarendraPathai - yes sir.

Comment: oh no no, i am beginner in java so want to know about it. otherwise still i don't have posted such a question.

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file  helps you. It was already asked here on stackoverflow.

Comment: There are plenty open executable generators available. You can view their source if you are curious. Such type of questions are not good for SO. read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @NarendraPathai - sir if i generate only executable jar file then it will run in all computer but is it necessary to install JRE for that or it's not necessary ?

Comment: Obviously how do you suppose you execute a jar without a JRE installed? JRE - Java Runtime Environment, an environment that is needed to run a java program. Self explanatory.

Comment: @NarendraPathai - Ok thank you sir. that's why i need to make an independent exe file that will run easily on each platform.

Comment: BTW exe will not run on each platform but just Windows. That is the reason Java also has platform dependent installers. There is no way to cater that.

Comment: yes i know that it will run only on windows platform. it's better to make exe of it then to install JRE on all PC. and client PC are windows based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to create executables from JAR files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSMOOTH to wrap your jar file into .exe file. 
from wiki ->JSmooth is a tool for wrapping Java JAR files into Windows Portable Executable EXE files.

For more info you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765371/how-can-i-create-executable-file-for-the-program-written-on-java)

Comment: JSMOOTH requires admin access in our environment which is actually not possible for me in out environment.

Answer (score 1):

First export your project as a `*.jar` in eclipse.

Then, you can use JSmooth to make an `*.exe` file.

Links:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html

http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to generate an EXE from a jar file is to use whats known as a "wrapper".

one of the more popular wrappers is http://www.jwrapper.com/ which i belive mojang uses to wrap minecraft for windows.

However if you want to generate a purely native EXE that runs as a standalone you will need a native compiler for example: http://jnc.mtsystems.ch.

At the end of the day java is designed to run on a VM double clicking on windows opens it up anyway, but if you really do want to make an EXE then the above methods should work.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago Microsoft use to be able to generate exe from java code, but I do not believe that Eclipse has this feature.

Comment: then what to do for that ?? any guidance sir ??

Comment: JSmooth .exe wrapper
java jar file to exe executable JSmooth is a Java Executable Wrapper. It creates native Windows launchers (standard .exe) for your java applications. It makes java deployment much smoother and user-friendly, as it is able to find any installed Java VM by itself. When no VM is available, the wrapper can automatically download and install a suitable JVM, or simply display a message or redirect the user to a web site.
JSmooth provides a variety of wrappers for your java application, each of them having their own behaviour: 
Download: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @ScaryWombat believe you're referring to [Visual J++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B)