# Convert Java project into Installation file

Tags: java

I'm working under a java desktop application project. I completed my java project using eclipse and it has many packages and class files in separate packages. My main class is Mainframe. My problem is I have to install this project into another computer, how can I convert my project to installation file?

Comment: create a `.war` or `.jar` file and deploy it

Comment: Possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458682/how-to-generate-executable-of-java-project-in-eclipse

Comment: What do you mean by "install on another computer"? Just copy the source code and rebuild the project, or make a "runnable" GUI only?

Answer (score 0):

As the [Help page](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm) says:

> To create a new runnable JAR file in the workbench:
>
> 1. From the menu bar's File menu, select Export.
> 2. Expand the Java node and select Runnable JAR file. Click Next.
> 3. In the  Opens the Runnable JAR export wizard Runnable JAR File Specification page, select a 'Java Application' launch configuration
>    to use to create a runnable JAR.
> 4. In the Export destination field, either type or click Browse to select a location for the JAR file.
> 5. Select an appropriate [library handling](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm&anchor=library-handling) strategy.
> 6. Optionally, you can also create an ANT script to quickly regenerate a previously created runnable JAR file.

[image]

**If you want to export it in a manner that allows another user to *import and edit* it, than export it as an archive:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the this method create only one class file to runnable JAR file. But I have many classes in many different packages.

Comment: @Viji A JAR file can only have one executable class, but it includes all dependencies needed for it to run

Comment: @Viji you must be doing something wrong. Exporting a runnable jar includes *every thing*, even libraries, so long as they are in the same project.

Comment: I done archive file, but how can I change it to windows intstallation file?

Comment: @Viji do you something like `exe` or  `msi`?

Comment: @Cardinal First I done JAR file and next is archive file that is ZIP format. You mentioned two types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Launch4j (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to be able to create executable files (.exe) from Java projects.